# Is "Provincial Centre for Public Administration Services" correct phrase?

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

My little province in Vietnam has just established a center, which is meant to be a central place for all services provided by the local government that the provincial citizens can come and deal with services, such as paying taxes, renewing driver licenses, applying for building permits, etc... in one convenient place.

I know the phrase in Vietnamese, but I need to translate it into English.

I wonder if my translation below is correct for the above context?

"Provincial Centre for Public Administration Services"

Thank you in advance.

Regards
Tien

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it.  As @natbergu suggests below, there are probably several ways it could be worded.  And there are of course UK/US style issues on whether you use "centre" or "center", and (for some wordings) whether you treat "administration" as a common or a "mass" noun (and hence whether you pluralize it).

Answer (score 1):

The term 'One Stop Shop' is used by many local authorities in the UK for this sort of provision. Examples are [Liverpool City Council](https://liverpool.gov.uk/one-stop-shops/) and [Cornwall Council](https://www.cornwall.gov.uk/council-and-democracy/contacting-the-council/one-stop-shops/) (Cornwall is a mainly rural area).

In order to reduce the need for residents to travel a UK authority with One Stop Shops will usually have a number of them all offering the same services rather than a central point such as yours. But the description of the services offered sounds very similar to the concept behind the UK One Stop Shops.

One possible difference is that a UK One Stop Shop might not be in the same building as the 'back office' for all the services provided (there would be only one local taxation office and only one planning department for example) but there will be good telephone and computer connections between the One Stop Shop and the back offices so that enquiries can be dealt with effectively.

I find it interesting that your Provincial government issues driving licences. These, and vehicle registrations, are managed centrally in the UK by the [Driver and Vehicle Licensing Agency](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/driver-and-vehicle-licensing-agency) or DVLA.

Comment: In the US, driver's licenses and vehicle registrations are, generally speaking, handled by the individual states.

Comment: this is very similar to One Stop Shop as you mentioned, but it is more like a link to other departments in the province. People can get the driver license here, but internally, it would be linked to the appropriate department such as Road Authority.

Comment: @N.T.C That's what I meant by the 'back office' functions being in different buildings. I think you have a One Stop Shop.

Answer (score -2):

"Provincial Centre for Public Administrations" would help it to be more concise.

"[...] for Public Services" would bolster the understanding.

These are just guesses, as there is no such place where I live.

Comment: "Provincial Centre for Public Administration Services" is fine, although, being from the US, I would recommend "Center" instead of "Centre".  But that's a matter of taste: both "Center" and "Centre" are correct.